# Can I make :cn use path in vim?

Tags: vim

I am trying to use quickfix to trace through Python errors.  After running Python via makeprg, the `:copen` window contains something like the following:

```
./test_semismooth.py|110| in <module>
./test_semismooth.py|57| in test_semismooth 
/Users/irving/otherlab/other/sim/SemismoothStatic.py|82| in update AttributeError: 'SolverProps' object has no attribute 'solver_props'
```

If I trace back and forth throw errors with `:cn`/`:cp`, the absolute filename works fine but it fails to find `test_semismooth.py` even though it is in `path`, which looks like

```
path=,.,~/physbam,~/otherlab/otherfab,~/duck,~/pentago,~/otherlab/other/sim,~/otherlab/other
```

Specifically, `test_semismooth.py` is in `~/otherlab/other/sim` (the current directory is `~/otherlab/other`).

Why isn't quickfix using path?  Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to use path, but changing `errorformat` to understand the working directory of the script fixed the problem.  Specifically,

1. Print `Entering directory '$dir'` before `cd`'ing into the script directory.
2. Add `%DEntering directory '%f'` to my `errorformat` definition in `.vimrc`.